# Is there any method of finding volume in a high dimensional cube between two planes?

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to know the volume of this region:

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, ($x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$)

$0<x_i<1$ for $i=1, 2, \dots, n$ (just a cube), and

$0< \epsilon_1 < x_1 + x_2 + \dots +x_n < \epsilon_2 < n$ (two planes).

Is there any method or formula to get this volume??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "planes" should be "hyperplanes".

Comment: @Community I don't see where there is an ambiguity !

Comment: As I understand, you mean volume between two hyperplanes. If yes, then it is simply $n-1$ dimensional integral on cube projection.

Comment: @zkutch Can I know what the cube projection is? Or can you give me any reference for that? Or do you mean just the multiple integral?

Comment: [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) would be of interest.

Comment: @user10354138 Wow Thanks! That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume, that hyperplanes are given by formulas
$$x_n=f_1(x_1,\cdots, x_{n-1}) = a_1x_1+ \cdots + a_{n-1}x_{n-1}$$
$$x_n=f_2(x_1,\cdots, x_{n-1}) = b_1x_1+ \cdots + b_{n-1}x_{n-1}$$
and we know that $f_1(x_1,\cdots, x_{n-1}) \leqslant f_2(x_1,\cdots, x_{n-1})$. Then
$$V=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\cdots \int\limits_{0}^{1} \Big(f_2(x_1,\cdots, x_{n-1})-f_1(x_1,\cdots, x_{n-1})\Big)dx_1 \cdots dx_{n-1}$$
If hyperplanes have intersection inside cube, then we should find it and divide integral in two parts.

Method and examples you can find in  G.M. Fichtenholz, Differential and Integral Calculus(Russian), 3-d volume, 2003, from page 439. As I know, there is also translation on German:

Hochschulbuecher fuer Mathematik, Bd. 61 (1986), XIV, 572 S.; Bd. 62 (1986),  836 S.; Bd 63 (1992),  564 pp. Berlin: VEB Deutscher Verlag der Wissenschaften.